# Can this mobile app be created with HTML 5 and JS or do I need native capabilites?

Tags: android, iphone, html

I would like the application to have the following capabilities:

The user would be given a timed, periodic alert (with sound) during certain times through the day upon which he/she is prompted to fill-in a quick survey. The information from the survey would then be sent off to an app server/db (this part would obviously be coded in a server-side language).

Would this be possible with HTML 5 / Javascript or would a framework such as phonegap or rhomobile have to be used?

Comment: Do some R&D before post a question.

Comment: You'll need a native app to do what you are trying to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use a native app. There's no way for a website to do anything in the background through safari, and no way for safari to notify the user of anything if the website isn't in the foreground.

Timed periodic alerts are exactly what push notifications are for. Push notifications are only available to native apps. Push notifications will show the user an alert and let them launch the app. They also let you send a small amount of metadata into the app with the notification.

Comment: But what about the WebSockets API? Is it too early too use this technology?

Comment: Even with WebSockets the browser will get closed and then so will the websocket.

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can for that you have to use phonegap. below are some reference :

http://phonegap.com/start/

http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/30862722/phonegap-android-eclipse-quickstart

Comment: I was trying to avoid going hybrid. My question was whether HTML5 would suffice.

Comment: i think you need to use something like phonegap or titanium, not sure if it possible without them